# @media remove top:0; from style

Tags: html, css, media-queries

So I've been wasting a ton of time on this little thing. Hoping someone around here can help me out.

I have a right side navigation panel.

```
.navbar_right{
 width: 365px;
 top:0;
 height:100%;
 position:fixed;
 right:0;
}
```

Now when my website breaks at the width of 1400, I want that same menu placed to the right, but at the bottom instead of the top.
So how do I go about removing `top:0;` and adding `bottom:0;` instead.

```
@media (max-width: 1400px) {
 .navbar_right{
 bottom:0;
 height:40%;
 }
}
```

I would prefer to be able to use the same container, as the platform I'm working on will be pushing content into the navigation panel, so if I can achieve this small thing - I'll save a lot of resources. Also I'd prefer to avoid jQuery for the same reason. Is it possible to stick with this one box, maybe delete a class and add another one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.navbar_right{
 width: 365px;
 position:fixed;
 right:0;
}

@media (max-width: 1400px) {
 .navbar_right{
 bottom:0;
 height:40%;
 }
}

@media (min-width: 1399px) {
 .navbar_right{
 top:0;
 height:100%;
 }
}
```

Comment: You know, sometimes you can stare at something for so long - and miss the obvious solution. Thank you good sir. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Set `top` to its initial value, which is `auto`:

```css
top: auto;
```

When you don't know the initial value, you can also use `initial`:

```css
top: initial;
```

Or, since `top` in not inheritable, `unset` will also reset it to the initial value:

```css
top: unset;
```

Or, if you want to roll back the cascade to the user level, use `revert`:

```css
top: revert;
```

Also see [CSS Cascading and Inheritance Level 4 - Explicit Defaulting](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#defaulting-keywords).